# GetInt can only be called from main thread?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

This question HAS been answered before but I tried everything and it didn't work.

I have this int in a flappy bird clone where you collect coins and it goes up by one kinda like a coin counter.

Every time you collect a coin it does

```
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coin", coin);
    coin+=1
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

And when a new coin spawns I do this in the very start of the class (not in void Start() )

```
private int coin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coin");
```

And everything worked fine.
**I even tested it by putting a print in console code and it counted down the coins just fine!**

But I also have this other scene called Shop, where you can spend those coins. However I made like a little way to draw those integers, that should work fine, BUT I get an error that getInt can only be called from main thread, which is dumb because I cant put it in the start / awake / update method, because when I do so I get a ton more errors.

What do I do? I want to call the coin integer that I saved using playerprefs in that scene in order to draw the amount of coins

I try calling it like this: `private int coin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coin");`
but I get an error, even though I don't get one when I call it in the actual game scene.

Full code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpriteScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int coin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coin");
    public Sprite num1;
    public Sprite num2;
    public Sprite num3;
    public Sprite num4;
    public Sprite num5;
    public Sprite num6;
    public Sprite num7;
    public Sprite num8;
    public Sprite num9;
    public Sprite num0;
    private int spritenum;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>(); // we are accessing the SpriteRenderer that is attached to the Gameobject
        if (spriteRenderer.sprite == null) // if the sprite on spriteRenderer is null then
            spriteRenderer.sprite = num0; // set the sprite to sprite1
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (coin < 10)
        {
            spritenum = coin;
            if (coin > 10)
            {
                if (coin < 20)
                {
                    spritenum = coin - 10;
                }
                if (coin > 20)
                {
                    if (coin < 30)
                    {
                        spritenum = coin - 20;
                    }
                    if (coin > 30)
                    {
                        if (coin < 40)
                        {
                            spritenum = coin - 30;
                        }
                        if (coin > 40)
                        {
                            if (coin < 50)
                            {
                                spritenum = coin - 40;
                            }
                            if (coin == 50)
                            {
                                spritenum = coin - 50;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ChangeTheDamnSprite();

    }
    void ChangeTheDamnSprite()
    {
        if (spritenum == 0)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = num0;
        }
        if (spritenum == 1)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = num1;
        }
        if (spritenum == 2)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = num2;
        }
        if (spritenum == 3)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = num3;
        }
        if (spritenum == 4)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = num4;
        }
        if (spritenum == 5)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = num5;
        }
        if (spritenum == 6)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = num6;
        }
        if (spritenum == 7)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = num7;

        }
        if (spritenum == 8)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = num8;
        }
        if (spritenum == 9)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = num9;
        }
    }
}
```

By the way if you're wondering, it pretty much looks how many coins you have and replaces the sprite to match the number, please don't question the stupid way I used to draw the coin amount, can you please help me fix the problem? As I said I tried putting it in start method, nothing happens, instead more errors.

**Oh and im building to android if that changes anything**

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/305882/how-do-i-invoke-functions-on-the-main-thread.html

Comment: I doubt this helps but thanks?

Comment: That's what you need to do, you need to call the code which does the draw on the main thread, you stated `I made like a little way to draw those integers`, that can't be done on a secondary thread, so you need a queue to call these things on main thread, check the second answer, it proposes a package which will help you do that

Comment: with draw I ment "draw" as in change the sprite each time. You see, when you have one coin, the game object is going to have a sprite with the number "1" written on it. No actual drawing, just a sprite change.
You can read the code to get an idea although its pretty complicated.
**Even if this is the way of solving the problem, which again I doubt it is, because I have another game object with code that has nothing to do with drawing in the same scene, and I get the same problem when I try to get coins from player pref, even if it solves it, isnt there an easier way than this?**

Comment: You can't manipulate (load/unload/change) a texture outside main thread, so that's the same case. Also, adding the exact exception would be very helpful to see what's happening...

Comment: ArgumentException: GetInt can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.
UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.GetInt (System.String key) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/PlayerPrefsBindings.gen.cs:48)
Coin..ctor ()

_Sure. Forgot about that_

Comment: Well, it's really clear then `Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function`. 
Change `private int coin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coin");` to `private int coin;` and add to Start `coin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coin");`

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to call this in `Awake()` or `Start()`?

Comment: I can swear to everything I believe in I had already tried this and it didn't work. However thank you so much, it worked, I'm sorry if I wasted your time with this, however your help was really appriciated. Couldn't thank you enough :-).

Comment: Just a sidenote: I'd suggest having some class that is persistent between scenes (singleton, DontDestroyOnLoad) and store stuff like coin count in that and only load/save from/to PlayerPrefs on gamestart and end.

Comment: It is totally inconceivable you need another thread.  Show us your code where you think you are taking "another thread".

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're approaching this problem the wrong way. May I suggest you create a new class called CoinController : Monobehaviour and attach it to your player.

```
public class CoinController: MonoBehaviour {
    int coins;

    public int Coins {
        get {
            return coins;
        }
    }

    public Sprite GetSprite() {
        //logic for determining sprite based on number of coins here
    }


    public void AddCoins(int num) {
        coins += num;
    }

    public void SpendCoins(int num) {
        coins -= num;
    }
}


CoinController coinController = GetComponent<CoinController>();
coinController.AddCoins(5);
coinController.SpendCoins(2);

//in update method
Sprite thisSprite = coinController.GetSprite();
//draw sprite logic, not sure how you're doing this, but DrawCoinSprite would be some method that updates which sprite to draw
DrawCoinSprite(thisSprite);
```

I hope that helps!